# Can NodeJs - http module be hosted to process ASP/.NET web site pages?

Tags: node.js, httpmodule

I want to host website locally which would be accessed with a embedded Browser Control on a Desktop application.
I am trying to find a solution by hosting a http listener with the capability to process the ASP.NET/CSHTML(Razor) server pages.
NodeJS is an option to host a http listner, but how to register/associate the ASP Http Handler to NodeJs-HttpModule for processing these server pages.

Is this possible?

Thank you very much for your interest in my query. Please help.

Comment: How about simply redirect the requests to your Node.js application?

Comment: No, it won't as the Http listner (Node.js) doesn't understand the *.aspx or *.cshtml requests.

Comment: I already has the ASP.NET site created and hosted on IIS, which is available globally to my customers. But i want to move this site locally with a webserver(http listner) along with my desktop application.

Comment: You may extract the data (e.g. params, body, headers) from the requests, then treat IIS as a proxy and call the Node.js application's API with the extracted params.